# How to email HTML inputs from page to user via a separate contact form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a number of HTML inputs that users control as part of a Javascript-run calculator (i.e. they input their age, income, etc. and the script spits out a number)

How can I use a separate contact form that dynamically retrieves the inputs and value from that calculation and sends to the user when they supply their email? I have the email form working via Contact Form 7. I just can't figure out how to access the variables on the webpage.

Would I have to create URL variables? Or can I retrieve data via their IDs?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are your forms on the same page? Can you put your workflow in step by step order?

Comment: Certainly. To clarify, I use range and number type inputs on a page. The inputs given are used to calculate a final number. The number is presented to them using Javascript.

On the same page, at the bottom, I have a contact form asking for their email only. This is used to send them an email. In the email, I want to use custom tags that pull data from the page elements using their IDs.

Comment: Oh, that'll be easy. What are you using to write the calculator?

Comment: Well that's good to hear! I'm a beginner, so I don't know what's possible. I use Javascript to calculate and change innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do what I want.

My HTML elements that Javascript updates already have unique IDs. Each form element also needs a unique ID, so that I can edit with my Javascript calculator function via:

document.getElementById('inputFieldID').value = document.getElementById('pageElementID').textContent;

I also used the Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension so that I could give all of my form variables the [dynamichidden] tag. This way, I can include in my email many tags that never show up in the form.